# Передача данных ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-intent

В приложении для android у меня есть три Activity, Activity1, Activity2, Activity3 все они открываются в таком же порядке. Я пытаюсь передать из Activity1 данные ArrayList в Activity3 не затрагивая при этом Activity2,но это не получается
Код Activity1для передачи ArrayList:

```
ArrayList <String> ar=new ArrayList<>();
Intent i = new Intent(this,Activity2.class);
                i.putStringArrayListExtra("text1", ar);
                startActivity(i);
```

Открывается Activity2,в ней мы переходим в Activity3.
Код Activity3 для приёма ArrayList из Activity1:

```
ArrayList <String> url=new ArrayList<>();
url = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("text1");
```

Подскажите,как реализовать данный "перескок",что бы данные ушли из Activity1 в Activity3?

Comment: Покажите момент перехода на Activity3 из Acitvity2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в коде в `Activity3` в строке `url = getIntent()...;` вы получаете интент, который вы создавали в `Activity2` для старта `Activity3`. Вы туда похоже ничего не положили, и, соответственно, в `Activity3` вы ничего не получите.

Поэтому тут такие варианты:

- Для того, чтоб *"данные ушли из `Activity1` в `Activity3`"* вам нужно и стартовать `Activity3` из `Activity1`;
- Поочерёдно тащить нужные данные через каждую активити `Activity1 -> Activity2 -> Activity3`.
- Быть крутым разработчиком и использовать библиотеку [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) от GreenRobot :)

Comment: А без "тащить" других возможных вариантов нет?  Мой вопрос впринципи в этом и заключался,как обойтись без дополнительного кода в Activity2

Comment: @Владимир обновил)

Comment: А как с помощью EventBus реализовать мою проблему?

Comment: @Владимир реализовывать проблемы не нужно) Использование EventBus в решении вашей задачи - это уже другой вопрос. Вкратце, вы в одной активити опубликуете объект, а в другой активити подпишитесь на получение этого объекта. И не нужно будет "тащить" всё через несколько активити. По ссылке в ответе есть вся необходимая информация для подключения и использования библиотеки

Comment: Спасибо за ответ,буду изучать

Comment: Быть `крутым разработчиком` это значит использовать чей-то велосипед, который своими руками можно написать за 2 минуты? `крутой разработчик` не видит способов передать данные между активностями, кроме интентов и `EventBus`? И других проблем во всём этом он тоже не видит? Странный какой-то разработчик, а не крутой.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin, напишите свой ответ, озвучьте другие способы, тут всем интересно

Comment: @PeterSamokhin если вы знаете лучшее решение - поделитесь им, к чему эта интригующая потетика. Опять же , зачем писать свой велосипед две минуты, когда есть уже готовый и не факт, что ваш двухминутный велосипед поедет лучше оттестированного и проверенного велосипеда от признаной команды.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin, я сам ни разу не использовал ни EventBus от GreenRobot, ни Otto от Square, я писал свой event bus на rxjava (велосипед), который отлично работает и с простыми ui-событиями, так и с кучей объектов, которые ловит websocket и гоняет по всему приложению с кешированием и отображением в ui. Поэтому я как джуниор с радостью бы узнал, что можно использовать для таких задач, если не так скажем сам паттерн event bus

Comment: @pavlofff интригующая потетика к тому, что `крутость` разработчика, соответствующего вышеописанным критериям, очень сильно под вопросом. Описанный чуть выше в комментариях `радостный джуниор` — вполне, `крутой разработчик` — вряд ли.

Comment: EventBus вполне себе решила мою задачу,конечно в моём случае я хотел использовать кода по минимому,кажется что задача не так уж и сложна,зато для себя расширил ассортимент библиотек,да и даже в документации гугл рекомендуют порой использовать библиотеки,по типу glide u picasso для работы с изображениями,значит это не зазорно,раз они сами это говорят